# PHP Permutations with limited string length

Tags: php, permutation

I am using someones permutation solution in PHP that was given off stack and was wondering if there was a way for me to limit the character count in the string to be a fixed amount? Lets say I want to limit the string length to only 4 characters. To be honest, I'm not sure really whats going on in this formula and was hoping I could modify it, but I would also be interested in a new formula approach as well especially if its faster from another individual. Thanks

```
ini_set('memory_limit', '1024M');

function permutations(array $elements)
{
    if (count($elements) <= 1) {
        yield $elements;
    } else {
        foreach (permutations(array_slice($elements, 1)) as $permutation) {
            foreach (range(0, count($elements) - 1) as $i) {
                yield array_merge(
                    array_slice($permutation, 0, $i),
                    [$elements[0]],
                    array_slice($permutation, $i)
                );
            }
        }
    }
}


$list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];

$newlist = array();
foreach (permutations($list) as $permutation) {
    //echo implode(',', $permutation) . PHP_EOL;
    array_push($newlist, implode(',', $permutation));
}


echo sizeof($newlist);
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this code? What does it give you as output?

Comment: @vivek_23  The output is a list of combinations from the $list variable that exist. So combinations such as a,b,c,e,d,f & a,b,c,d,f,e etc..... I think with those characters being checked alone its like 5000 possible combinations exist.

Comment: Ok, but all I see is the `echo sizeof($newlist);` to print the size which is probably 6! for `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']`.

Comment: Also, what do you mean by `Lets say I want to limit the string length to only 4 characters`? Can you give an example?

Comment: @vivek_23 I was just doing that sizeof function to see how big the list was getting :) Limited character length meaning like so instead of outputting a,b,c,d,e,f it will output a,b,c,d instead

Comment: In that case, you would be getting repeated permutations. Like, the actual permutations would be `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'e']`, but stripping of the last 2 characters would get you `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'],['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`

Comment: @vivek_23  So am I looking for something other than permutations? Because I doubt that I want to check against my list to see if that character list already exist since the list might be kinda slow to run

Comment: Why not just go with 4 characters right from the start? Generate permutations on `[a,b,c,d]` itself

Comment: @vivek_23 My final solution needs to account for all letter and numbers. I'm just using the example code as fill space of what I found. I figured the code could be modified potentially or maybe I'm approaching this wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an adaptation of the function that allows you to put a limit on the number of characters as second argument.

You need to add an extra parameter to know how many remaining characters are allowed and decrement it on the recursive call :

```
function permutations(array $elements, $limit)
{
    if( $limit == 1 )
    {
        // No need to go deeper, return a list of all remaining letters
        foreach($elements as $element)
            yield array($element);
    }

    foreach($elements as $i => $element)
    {
        // compute all the permutions, without the elements at index i
        $sub_perms = permutations( array_merge(array_slice($elements, 0, $i), array_slice($elements, $i+1)), $limit-1);

        // list all the permutations with the currently selected element + all the possible combinations of $limit-1 letters of the others elements 
        foreach($sub_perms as $sub_perm)
        {
            yield array_merge(array($element), $sub_perm);
        }
    }
}
```

You can then call `permutations($list, 2)` or `permutations($list, 4)` to have all the permutations of 2 or 4 characters.